# How to add bullet point to fieldset on button click?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am making a google docs like site, and I am currently making a button that when clicked, will add a bullet point at the location of the cursor. I tried execommand, but that didn't work for me. I don't want there to be a bullet point on every click of the enter key, like some of the other posts here on this site.

Here is my HTML5 Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Editor</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="buttons">
      <button
        class="bold"
        onclick="document.execCommand('bold',false,null);"
        title="Bold"
      >
        
      </button>

      <button
        class="italic"
        onclick="document.execCommand('italic',false,null);"
        title="Italic"
      >
        
      </button>

      <button
        class="underline"
        onclick="document.execCommand('underline',false,null);"
        title="Underline"
      >
        U̲
      </button>

      <input
        type="color"
        class="color-picker"
        id="colorPicker"
        oninput="changeColorText(this.value);"
        title="Change text color"
      />

      <button id="highlight"><mark>Highlight</mark></button>

      <button id="bullet point">•</button>
    </div>

    <fieldset class="userInput" contenteditable="true"></fieldset>
    <script src="use.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

And here is my JavaScript Code:

```
var boldBtn = document.querySelector(".bold");
var italicBtn = document.querySelector(".italic");
var underlineBtn = document.querySelector(".underline");
var colorPicker = document.querySelector(".color-picker");
var highlightBtn = document.querySelector("#highlight");
var bulletPointBtn = document.querySelector("#bullet point");

boldBtn.addEventListener("click", function () {
  boldBtn.classList.toggle("inUse");
});

italicBtn.addEventListener("click", function () {
  italicBtn.classList.toggle("inUse");
});

underlineBtn.addEventListener("click", function () {
  underlineBtn.classList.toggle("inUse");
});

highlightBtn.addEventListener("click", function () {
  highlightBtn.classList.toggle("inUse");
});

const changeColorText = (color) => {
  document.execCommand("styleWithCSS", false, true);
  document.execCommand("foreColor", false, color);
};

document.getElementById("highlight").addEventListener("click", function () {
  var range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0),
    span = document.createElement("span");

  span.className = "highlight";
  span.appendChild(range.extractContents());
  range.insertNode(span);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find list of commands available for .execCommand [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand). There is insertUnorderedList command that might do the trick for you.

Other than that, you can always implement wanted functionality using Javascript, but you might need additional research for that.